Find a prime P, and add digit 1 or 3 to the right end of this number(after the unit digit) per second, Do you think the new data always be prime?
Bob selects a prime number, and then every second, he adds the digit $1$ or $3$ to the right end of this number  (after the unit digit), such that the new number is also a prime, can Bob continue indefinitely?
I calculated:
The prime No is $3k+1$, or $3k+2$; So if $3k+2$, you cant add any digit $1$, which will be divided by $3$. of if $3k+1$ you can only add 1 time digit 1, and all others are $3$. So this question becomes add $3$ always.
$ p1=$prime;
$p2=10P1+3$ is prime or not?
p3=10p2+3
p4=10P3+3?
obviously will meet composite no, How to prove?

What have you tried?

Welcome to MSE. In this forum you're expected to show some work of your own in order to get help.

Connected. See as well Wikipedia page about (right)truncable primes here.

Sad that this interesting question is presented utterly contextless. Pleas provide any trials (for examples search for a long valid sequence) , then this can become a really good question.

@Peter, there's a limit to how good a question can become, when the answer has been known for decades and is widely available in books & on websites.

@Gerry Myerson "when the answer has been known for decades" maybe by you, surely because you have a good knowledge of the domain, but not by me for example (it has taken me some time before  catching the good keywords to find the sites I have indicated above)... and a fortiori not by a student...

@GerryMyerson This makes it a duplicate and gives a close-reason , this does however not prevent a question to be a good question. Also , I was not aware of this either. I heard from right truncatable primes , but this is not quite what is asked here. Here we do not start with a single digit , but with an arbitary prime.
